# How to make UITableView with subclass of UITableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There are no good answer here. So I wonder how to make this.
For example, in customClass of UITableViewCell I want to make a prototype cell with a photo and label.

```
    class myCell: UITableViewCell {
    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
   }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    ....
    }



 class myController: UIViewController {
....
}
```

I wonder you guys first register myCell in myController and then

```
the cell = let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell() so on.
```

if I register myCell in myController, there in no need to use

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
   }
```

. If I don't use below, how do I add subview to UITableViewCell view?

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
       }
```

Note: I want to register cell because I only load cell onetime. And make cell reusable with `dequeueReusableCell()`

Can you show me how to do this professionally please? 
You can use your own method. I just want a prototype cell with a photo and label. And all process in programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define your own table view cell class:

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "CustomCell"

    // properties, etc., e.g.:
    private let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // here you do the setup, adding subviews, etc., e.g.:
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //other methods, e.g., for configuring the cell, e.g.:
    func configure(withTitle title: String) {
        label.text = title
    }

}
```

And then you simply use it in your `CustomTableController`:

```
class CustomTableController: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate var data: [Model] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        // registering a cell class for reuse is important
        // but it's enough to make it once in viewDidLoad
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // here you can dequeue your cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // configure the cell using model, e.g.:
        cell.configure(withTitle: data[indexPath.row].title)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same as I did. My problem I don't call init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) method anywhere. So How it  adds subview to cell view? When I register it adds ? I am confused.

Comment: @John when you call `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, if there is no existing cell already created, the `tableView` will instantiate a new cell using `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` initializer - that's why you have to call `super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)` and why I recommend setting the cell up in that particular initializer... in case of cell reusing, you do NOT create instances of cell yourself, you leave it to the `tableView` and ask for the cells using `dequeueReusableCell` methods

Comment: @John I added some examples in the answer, check it out now

Comment: Thank you very much I understand everything now. Especially why we use super.init too.

Comment: One more thing I want to I ask you because you are explaining very good. customCell.self here why we add self?

Comment: That's how you access a class meta type in swift (see https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/types-and-meta-types-in-swift-9cd59ba92295 )

Comment: Excuse me but I kind of confused later. tableView will instantiate override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) in the example and super.init has belong to UITableViewCell?

Comment: @John yes.. you are overriding an initializer, because you want to do some setup when a cell is instantiated. the `tableView` uses `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` initializer - therefore you override that initializer and do the setup there. the call to `super.init` is something you have to do, because the `UITableViewCell.init(style:reuseIdentifier)` does the necessary setup for reusing cells